# Scroll to top function stuck once activated(mobile)

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Hello, I'm currently practicing coding my own site, but i've ran into a problem. I added an auto fade in scroll to top button which works fine on desktop, but on mobile once it's activated the scroll gets stuck at the top. Any idea whats causing it to get stuck, here is my coding.**

*Sorry in advanced, im very new to this.*

### The Script

```
<script>
    const scrollTop = function () {
      // create HTML button element
      const scrollBtn = document.createElement("button");
      scrollBtn.innerHTML = "&uarr;";
      scrollBtn.setAttribute("id", "scroll-btn");
      document.body.appendChild(scrollBtn);
      // hide/show button based on scroll distance
      const scrollBtnDisplay = function () {
        window.scrollY > window.innerHeight
          ? scrollBtn.classList.add("show")
          : scrollBtn.classList.remove("show");
      };
      window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollBtnDisplay);
      // scroll to top when button clicked
      const scrollWindow = function () {
        if (window.scrollY != 0) {
          setTimeout(function () {
            window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY - 50);
            scrollWindow();
          }, 10);
        }
      };
      scrollBtn.addEventListener("click", scrollWindow);
    };
    scrollTop(); scrollTop: scrolled;
  </script>


</body>
</html>

</head>
</html>
```

### CSS

```
section::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
    #scroll-btn {
      opacity: 0;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #c066c0;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 10%;
      right: 10%;
      border: 2px solid #fff;
      border-radius: 50%;
      font: bold 40px monospace;
      transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
overflow: hidden;
    }
    #scroll-btn.show {
      opacity: 1;
      transition: opacity 1s, transform 1s;
overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Can anyone tell what the problem is?? Thanks so much!

Comment: Also on mobile once I pinch to zoom in and back out it deactivates and works normal again...

Comment: where's your `html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example of `scroll to top`

```js
const scrollToTop = document.querySelector(".scroll-to-top");

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (window.scrollY > 200) {
    scrollToTop.classList.add("visible");
  } else {
    scrollToTop.classList.remove("visible");
  }
});

scrollToTop.addEventListener("click", () => {
  window.scroll({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
});
```

```css
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/KunalTanwar/normalize/css/normalize.inter.min.css";

body {
  height: 200vh;
}

.scroll-to-top {
  --size: 48px;
  position: fixed;
  border: 0;
  right: 32px;
  bottom: 32px;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: grid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: var(--size);
  place-items: center;
  height: var(--size);
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  transform: scale(0);
  will-change: transform;
  background-color: white;
  transition: transform 250ms ease;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.scroll-to-top svg {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.scroll-to-top.visible {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<button class="scroll-to-top">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="ionicon" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
    <path d="M448 368L256 144 64 368h384z" />
  </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: Also, how to change the color of the arrow sign ?

Comment: `svg { fill: /* whatever color you want */; }`